# Finding local extrema of $f(x) = x^2 e^{-x}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, maxima-minima

I must find and identify (max or min) the local extrema of $f(x) = x^2 e^{-x}$.

This is a simple problem if it was in a calculus exam - but it's not. I'm not sure how to structure the solution for an analysis question.

Comment: Do you know how to differentiate $f(x)$ with respect to $x$?

Comment: Yes, I do. I could solve this if it was a calculus question.

Comment: I don't understand. It **is** a calculus question. Don't let these names ("analysis", "calculus", "algebra" and so on) mislead you. This is a specific question with a unique solution, regardless of who's the teacher or what class it was given in.

Comment: About my last comment: see this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ZED4gITL28

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\frac{df}{dx}=2x e^{-x}+x^2(-e^{-x})=(2x-x^2)e^{-x}$$

Extrema can occur only when $df/dx=0$, and $e^{-x}$ is always positive.